# getting permissions

Tags: ros, permission, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed ROS on both the Robot (netbook) and the desktop computers after installing UBUNTU.

I am running a roomba, but not a 5XX or a create.  I just need to CHANGE the port settings.

I tried to change a file by gedit turtlebot_node.py which was supposed to have the tty,usb0 inside. Once I changed it, it would not let me save it because I did not have permissions.

I have read the manuals and tried every which way to change it. Once I can see the port on the roomba and the kinect, then I can start doing the turtlebot, etc.

Any ideas welcome.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12053/getting-permissions/) by [MovieMaker](https://answers.ros.org/users/1184/moviemaker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-11-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a parameter to set the port for the node.  This is a much better solution than editing the code installed on your system.  The parameter is ~port.  See the [turtlebot_node wiki page](http://ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_node)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1